# Putting a CSS ribbon on the opposite side

Tags: html, css

I want to create a ribbon that goes around a container.

I have looked at the following tutorial:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/corner-ribbon/

However, I want to create a ribbon on the **left hand side** as opposed to the **right hand side**.

You would think this would be a trivial change, however I am really struggling! I tried flipping the rotation and changing the directions from right to left, but it ends up looking weird!

Here is the JS fiddle for the code (which is very similar to the URL, but has less code)

https://jsfiddle.net/anik786/9rg5u1q4/4/

Here is the HTML code:

```
 <div class="corner-ribbon-main-wrapper"><div class="ribbon-wrapper"><div class="ribbon">SALE!</div></div></div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.corner-ribbon-main-wrapper {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 280px; 
  height: 370px; 
  background: white;
  border-radius: 10px; 
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 90;
}

.ribbon-wrapper {
  width: 85px;
  height: 88px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  right: -3px;
}

.ribbon {
    font: bold 15px Sans-Serif;
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 0 1px 0;
    position: relative;
    padding: 7px 0;

    transform: rotate(45deg);

    left: -5px;
    top: 15px;
    width: 120px;

    background-color: #BFDC7A;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45);

    box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.ribbon:before, .ribbon:after {
    content: "";
    border-top: 3px solid #6e8900;
    border-left: 3px solid transparent;
    border-right: 3px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -3px;
}

.ribbon:before {
    left: 0;
}

.ribbon:after {
    right: 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Remove SCSS and converted it to plain CSS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add to `.ribbon`:

```
transform: rotate(-45deg);
left: -30px;
```

and position the container with:

```
left: -3px;
```

insteed of right value.

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/9rg5u1q4/6/)**

Comment: You seemed to have got it, but why is the `left: -30px` when originally it was `left: -5px`?

Comment: That value is the horizonal position of the ribbon with respect to his container `ribbon-wrapper` Depending of the rotating of a square you need different values to hide the "corners" you don't want to show moving them outside the wrapper... I know it seems confusing and I'm not very well explaining it but if you inpect your fiddle with crhome inpector (or simillar) and change the values step by step (select the left value and arrows up and down) you will get it fast.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your fiddle and Is this what you need ? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OyMJKR

```
.ribbon-wrapper {
  top: -3px; 
  left: -3px; /* Changed */
}
```